# How can I verify if a Text component is empty with Detox?

Tags: react-native, detox

Is it possible to **retrieve the text or the value** of a react-native component (e.g text-input)?

```
await expect(element(by.id('componentId'))).<method>
```

Comment: Apparently not, this open issue is welcome PRs to add it - https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/445

Comment: I used `await expect(element(by.id('componentId'))).toHaveText(text);`. I know this is not helpful, but at least some validations are available.

Comment: @vk.4884 this can be used to check the same text, I'd like to check if text in component is empty or not